# Question about writing to a file in Producer-Consumer program

Tags: c, linux, file, producer-consumer

I have to write two separate programs, which one is a Producer and second is a Consumer (both running in separate terminals). I provide an argument to the Producer which can be a text or a single character. Then, producer creates a `.txt` file, puts single character into it then closes it. Consumer opens that file, reads that character and prints it on a terminal, then closes the file and deletes it.The whole process repeats itself. If provided argument includes `*`, for example `*` or `text*` it finishes the both programs, printing `*` before ending. I can only use functions: `open()`, `close()`, `read()`, `write()`, `unlink()`. The expected result looks like this:

[image: expected result]

I have written both codes, this is the Producer code:

(I am aware of the fact that i have unnecessarily defined `SIZE` and used it, please don't mind it)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define SIZE 1

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char buff;
    do{
        int fdi=-1;
        while(fdi<0){
            fdi=open("test.txt",O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666);
        }
        read(STDIN_FILENO,&buff,SIZE);     
        write(fdi,&buff,SIZE);
        close(fdi);
    }while(buff!='*');
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the Consumer code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define SIZE 1

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char buff;
    do{
        int fdi=-1;
        while(fdi<0){
            fdi=open("test.txt",O_RDONLY | O_EXCL);
        }
        int rdin=read(fdi,&buff,SIZE);
        if(rdin>0){
        write(STDOUT_FILENO,&buff,SIZE);
        close(fdi);
        unlink("test.txt");
        }
        else{
        close(fdi);
        }
    }while(buff!='*');
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: how does the Producer program not insert more than a one character into the file? I mean, if I for example run the Producer program only, and provide argument `text`, it will insert in the file the letter `t` only, the rest will be inserted to other files. Shouldn't it loop and add the whole `text` word to one file? There is no statement that guarantees that file will contain one character, yet it contains only one character and I don't know why.

Comment: How do you know which `t` from `text` was written to the file?

Comment: What is `SIZE` in `read(STDIN_FILENO,&buff,SIZE);`? How many characters will that read?

Comment: @ScottHunter I just run "cat test.txt" and then "rm test.txt"  in other terminal and i can see the letter changing in the file "t->e->x->t"

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Its the size of buff, ive written in the post that i am aware of the fact that i defined it unnecessarily and could have just written 1 instead (since char size is 1 byte)

Comment: The `#define` is a good thing, the comment was in response to *"how does the Producer program doesn't insert more than a one character into the file?"*

Comment: @KonradRudolph No it doesn't, if i write "cat test.txt" in separate console i can see the contents. After I delete the file with "rm test.txt" the new file is created with next letter.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I understand that it loads only one char at a time, but i don't understand why doesn't it add next characters in next loops, for example, why isn't is "te" in the next loop.

Comment: @Towelyey Oh, I misunderstood the question then. Apologies. The comment about `O_EXCL` stands, though: it can’t be used like that (in particular, it can’t be used when opening the file for reading).

Answer (score 2):

I will limit my answer to your only specific question:

> how does the Producer program not insert more than a one character into the file?

You're doing the following in a loop:

```
do{
    int fdi = -1;
    while (fdi < 0){
        // Open the file only if it does not exist, creating it.
        fdi = open("test.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666);
    }

    // Read 1 char from stdin.
    read(STDIN_FILENO, &buff, SIZE);     

    // Write that char to the beginning of the file.
    write(fdi, &buff, SIZE);

    // Close and truncate the file.
    close(fdi);
} while(buff != '*');
```

The first time you open the file, it is also created. From the second time onwards, the combination of flags `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` will make `open()` fail with error `EEXIST`, since this combination of flags will open the file *only if it doesn't already exist*. After writing the first character, your program will run in an endless loop (`while (fdi < 0)`) trying to open the file a second time.

From [the manual page for `open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

> **O_EXCL**: Ensure  that  this  call  creates  the file: if this flag is specified in conjunction with O_CREAT, and pathname
>                already exists, then open() will fail.

So, first of all, you don't need the `O_EXCL` flag. Other than that, if you want to append data to the file instead of overwriting its content each time, you should add the `O_APPEND` flag when you `open()` the file. From the manual page:

> **O_APPEND**: The  file is opened in append mode.  Before each write(2), the file offset is positioned at the end of the file,
>                as if with lseek(2).  The modification of the file offset and the write operation  are  performed  as  a  single
>                atomic step.

Comment: I've run the Producer code and provided "hello" as an argument and the test.txt content is just 'h'. Ive made no changes to the code.

Answer (score 2):

In the producer, when you use the `O_CREAT` and `O_EXCL` flags when opening a file, the call will fail if the file already exists.  So on the first iteration of the outer loop (assuming the file doesn't exist) the file is created and the first character is written.  On the next iteration the `open` call fails because the file exists, so it sits in the inner loop for as long as the file exists.

In the consumer, the `open` call is done in a loop until it succeeds.  This will happen when the producer writes and closes the file.  The consumer then reads the character from the file and deletes it.  When the consumer deletes the file, the `open` call in the producer will succeed and write the second character to the file.

This process then repeats until a `*` character is read by the producer and written to the file, after which the producer exits.  Then when the consumer reads the `*` it also exits.